# Use R to calculate the total number of days in X number of bimonthly periods

Tags: r, lubridate

```
> df <- data.frame(begin_date = as.Date("2016-01-01") + c(1:10),
+                  term = c(11:20),
+                  term_unit = c(rep("bimonthly", 5), rep("monthly", 5))
+                 )
> df
   begin_date term term_unit
1  2016-01-02   11 bimonthly
2  2016-01-03   12 bimonthly
3  2016-01-04   13 bimonthly
4  2016-01-05   14 bimonthly
5  2016-01-06   15 bimonthly
6  2016-01-07   16   monthly
7  2016-01-08   17   monthly
8  2016-01-09   18   monthly
9  2016-01-10   19   monthly
10 2016-01-11   20   monthly
```

I want to calculate the number of days in the term for each row. The loan begins on begin_date and then the borrower makes the number of monthly or bimonthly(twice a month) payments indicated in the term column. So one month after the begin date, the first scheduled monthly payment would occur and the second scheduled bimonthly payment would occur (the first bimonthly would happen 15 days after begin_date).

If all term_units were monthly I could calculate the number of days

```
> library(lubridate)
df$term_days <- as.integer(df$begin_date %m+% months(df$term) - df$begin_date)
```

But I'm running into trouble when I try and calculate the number of days for the bimonthly terms.

```
> df$term_days <- ifelse(df$term_unit == "monthly", as.integer(df$begin_date %m+% months(df$term) - df$begin_date),
+                        ifelse((df$term/2) == floor(df$term/2), as.integer(df$begin_date %m+% months(df$term/2) - df$begin_date), 
+                               as.integer(df$begin_date %m+% months(floor(df$term/2)) - df$begin_date +15 )))
```

returns the error

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
invalid class “Period” object: periods must have integer values
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work by changing `%m+% months(df$term/2)` to `%m+% months(floor(df$term/2))` in the second line. If anyone has a more elegant solution I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a slight change to your code:

```
df$term_days <- ifelse(df$term_unit == "monthly", as.integer(df$begin_date 
%m+% months(df$term) - df$begin_date),ifelse((df$term/2) == floor(df$term/2), 
as.integer(df$begin_date %m+% months(floor(df$term/2)) - df$begin_date), 
as.integer(df$begin_date %m+% months(floor(df$term/2)) - df$begin_date +15 )))
```

You needed the an extra floor statement in the second `ifelse`